# Two chrome profiles working in parallel - C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing

I want to program 2 different profiles to work at the same time (in parallel) google search statements.
But the problem I'm having is that it only works properly when each profile is active. If 2 profiles are at the same time, the search for element, sendkey will be for the last open profile.
Please help me.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using System.IO;
using static System.Windows.Forms.Design.AxImporter;
using Keys = OpenQA.Selenium.Keys;
using System.Threading;

namespace Selenium
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ChromeDriverService service = null;
        ChromeOptions option = null;
        ChromeDriver driver = null;
        string pf_path1 = "";
        string pf_path2 = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void MoProfile()
        {
            service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.BinaryLocation = @"D:\Profiles\Braveportable\" + pf_path1 + @"\brave-portable.exe";
            option.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=D:\Profiles\Braveportable\" + pf_path2);
            option.AddArgument(@"--profile-directory=Default");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(service, option);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
  

      IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        element.SendKeys("toridochi");
        element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pf_path1 = @"2";
        pf_path2 = @"2\data\";
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MoProfile));
        th1.Start();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pf_path1 = @"3";
        pf_path2 = @"3\data\";
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MoProfile));
        th2.Start();
    }
}
```

}

Hi, I want to program 2 different profiles to work at the same time (in parallel) google search statements.
But the problem I'm having is that it only works properly when each profile is active. If 2 profiles are at the same time, the search for element, sendkey will be for the last open profile.
Please help me.

Comment: both threads are using "MoProfile"... seems like one of them should use another class/function for "MoProfile2"... or pass in new driver instances, profile/options.  I'd suggest one class that takes a new options object in the constructor.  (each class will be a new, separate instance of driver and options (with separate profiles... don't think you can use the same one for two drivers...)